# How to pass an ip address inside a thread argument as one argument?

Tags: python, arguments, ip, nmap

I am writing a recon tool for scanning networks with threading using threading module, but the threads gives me a type error and tells me that every character in the thread arg section is a single argument

```
 for host in nm.all_host():
        threadx = threading.Thread(target=some_function, args=(host))
        thread_list.appened(threadx)
        thread.start()
```

TypeError: some_function() takes exactly 1 argument (11 given)
11 given refers to the gateway address which has 11 characters including "."
13 given refers to the client address which has 13 characters  including "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string instead of a tuple, to pass a tuple you should add a comma after host like this:

```
threadx = threading.Thread(target=some_function, args=(host,))
```